# Same Count Value is Returned for Different Queries

Tags: php, mysql, function, class, pdo

I am writing a simple class and there is a public query function. Along with results and some other data, the function returns row count of returned results too. Everything works fine but the count returned is same for all queries.

Example:

```
    $db = DB::dbInstance();
    $count1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users")->count(); // i.e. 10 records
    $count2= $db->query("SELECT * FROM articles")->count(); // still 10 but they should not
```

As you can see in above queries that both are different and there are different record counts too, still the returned count is same for different queries. Any solution please? Here is my class snippet:

```
<?php
    class DB {
        private static $_instance;
        private $_pdo, $_query, $_results, $_count = 0, $_errors = false;

        private function __construct() {
            try {
                $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::info('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::info('mysql/dbname'), Config::info('mysql/dbuser'), Config::info('mysql/dbpass'));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die('Failed connecting to database');
            }
        }

        public static function dbInstance() {
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
                self::$_instance = new DB();
            }

            return self::$_instance;
        }

        public function query($sql = NULL, $params = array()) {
            $this->_errors = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                if(count($params)) {
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($params AS $param) {
                        $this->_query->bindValue($i, $param);
                        $i++;
                    }
                }

                if($this->_query->execute()) {
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                } else {
                    $this->_errors = true;
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }

        public function count() {
            return $this->_count;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you also post the part where you instanciate you $db object ?

Comment: @jiboulex I have updated the code, please have a look..

Comment: Actually, you have no way to check if the second request had been well processed. I mean, if you make one successful request and the the _count but then there is an error and you don't check for it, the _count will remain the same

Comment: There is a conception mistake imho, the query method of your db class should return a query result object or an error. The query result should countain the count and result if you want. Because the problem with your class is that your object will change properties everytime you perform a new request.

Comment: @jiboulex thanks for the suggestion though. Will recheck the code and will think once more about my concepts and possible outcomes

Comment: @jiboulex Fixed this by adding `$this->_count = 0;` line at beginning of my query function solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$this->_count 0;` line to the beginning of query function solved the bug for me. Now my function first sets the count to 0 and then if rows are returned, the value is changed else 0 is returned. Exactly what I was expecting.

My function now looks like this:

```
<?php
        public function query($sql = NULL, $params = array()) {
            $this->_errors = false;
            $this->_count = 0;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                if(count($params)) {
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($params AS $param) {
                        $this->_query->bindValue($i, $param);
                        $i++;
                    }
                }

                if($this->_query->execute()) {
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                } else {
                    $this->_errors = true;
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }
?>
```